# How to call a public function declared in SecondWIndow from Main WIndow

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

I have 2 Windows in my WPF application. I'm running the `SecondWindow` from `MainWindow` using a background `thread` like as follows.

```
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    SecondWindow sw = new SecondWindow(this);
    sw.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();
}));
newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();
```

and I also have Public Function in the SecondWindow Like this...

```
public async void hide_animate()
{
    //Some Stuff//
}
```

I want to call hide_animate from a `method` from my `MainWindow`

I tried some options I found by googling, but nothing seems to work. any help?

**Update:**
I've tried this to call the function but still nothing happening...

```
Window mywindow = FindMyWindow("SecondWindow");
if (mywindow != null)
{
    SeocondWinodw.hide_animate();
}

private Window FindMyWindow(string windowName)
{
    foreach (Window wnd in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (wnd.Title.ToUpper().Equals(windowName.ToUpper()))
        {
            return wnd;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is the issue in calling `sw.hide_animate()`?

Comment: not happening anything

Comment: Windows can't be run from background threads. There is only one GUI thread in WPF

Comment: well I'm successful at calling the window from a background thread. So that's not the problem. I just need to call that specific function derived in 2nd window from the mainwindow.